# VBA Macro : Compare / check 3 sheets and return differences value

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets that need to check if they have same value. All value on column B6 until last row should be same in Sheets MM, PP and CO. If there's difference value, the different value should be on highlight (the color is red).

But, my syntax didn't run. The syntax just can read if there's an empty column in range. This is my syntax.. **Not including highlight.** First, i tried to place the difference value to the other sheets. But, failed. Thank you.

```
Sub MatchValue()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer

LastRowB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MM").Range("B6:B" & LastRowB).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
y = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PP").Range("B6:B" & LastRowB).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
z = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CO").Range("B6:B" & LastRowB).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

If x <> y Then
MsgBox "MM <> PP", vbCritical, "Error Report"
End If
If y <> z Then
MsgBox "PP <> CO", vbCritical, "Error Report"
End If
If z <> x Then
MsgBox "CO <> MM", vbCritical, "Error Report"
End If

SheetMM = "MM"
DataColumnMM = "B6"
SheetPP = "PP"
DataColumnPP = "B6"
SheetCO = "CO"
DataColumnCO = "B6"
SheetUnmatched = "Data Unmatched"
DataColumnUnmatched = "A1"

DataRowMM = Range(DataColumnMM).Row
DataColMM = Range(DataColumnMM).Column
DataRowPP = Range(DataColumnPP).Row
DataColPP = Range(DataColumnPP).Column
DataRowCo = Range(DataColumnCO).Row
DataColCo = Range(DataColumnCO).Column
DataRowUnmatched = Range(DataColumnUnmatched).Row
DataColUnmatched = Range(DataColumnUnmatched).Column


LastDataMM = Sheets(SheetMM).Cells(Rows.Count, DataColMM).End(xlUp).Row
LastDataPP = Sheets(SheetPP).Cells(Rows.Count, DataColPP).End(xlUp).Row
LastDataCO = Sheets(SheetCO).Cells(Rows.Count, DataColCo).End(xlUp).Row
LastDataUnmathced = Sheets(SheetUnmatched).Cells(Rows.Count, DataColUnmatched).End(xlUp).Row

    For counter = DataRowMM To LastDataRowMM
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(LastDataPP, counter) = 0 Then
            LastDataUnmathced.Offset(1) = counter
        End If
    Next
    For counter = DataRowMM To LastDataRowMM
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(LastDataCO, counter) = 0 Then
            LastDataUnmathced.Offset(1) = counter
        End If
    Next
        For counter = DataRowPP To LastDataRowPP
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(LastDataCO, counter) = 0 Then
            LastDataUnmathced.Offset(1) = counter
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, you want to:

1. Check three tables across three sheets in the `ActiveWorkbook`
2. Check to see if the same number of constants exists in the table ranges
3. Highlight cells red where the values between the three sheets aren't the same

I've simplified the code in order to achieve these targets

```
Sub MatchValue()

  Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Range3 As Range

  With ActiveWorkbook
    With .Sheets("MM")            'First Sheet Name
      Set Range1 = .Range("B6")   'Address of first row on First Sheet
      Set Range1 = .Range(Range1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Range1.Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With .Sheets("PP")            'Second Sheet Name
      Set Range2 = .Range("B6")   'Address of first row on second Sheet
      Set Range2 = .Range(Range2, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Range2.Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With .Sheets("CO")            'Third Sheet Name
      Set Range3 = .Range("B6")   'Address of first row on third Sheet
      Set Range3 = .Range(Range3, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Range3.Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
  End With

'Delete this part if you don't want to remove the existing fill (might be handy)
  Range1.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
  Range2.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
  Range3.Interior.Pattern = xlNone

'Checks to see if the same number of constants exist within the test ranges
  If Range1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count <> _
     Range2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count Then
    MsgBox "Range 1 and Range 2 constant count doesn't match", vbCritical, "Error Report"
  ElseIf Range2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count <> _
         Range3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count Then
    MsgBox "Range 1 and Range 2 constant count doesn't match", vbCritical, "Error Report"
  End If

  Dim Temp1 As Variant, Temp2 As Variant, Temp3 As Variant, x As Long

'Checks to see if all the values entered are the same, if not, fills them red
  Temp1 = Range1.Value
  Temp2 = Range2.Value
  Temp3 = Range3.Value

  For x = 1 To UBound(Temp1, 1)
    If Temp1(x, 1) <> Temp2(x, 1) Or _
       Temp2(x, 1) <> Temp3(x, 1) Then
      Range1.Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Range2.Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Range3.Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
  Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: ah, thank you so much! very appreciated. but there's an error in line `With .Sheets("MM")             'First Sheet Name` . Error: Object Required. i think your code already great.

Comment: Fixed it. I had made a typo when adding 'ActiveWorkbook'. If it works, meets your needs, and taught you something, please accept the answer :-).

Comment: ah, sorry. that's my fault. i didn't see the typo. and your code run sooo smoothly. very very great! thank you so much for your help! also there's a typo in line `Range2.Interior.Pattern = xlNone` , bro. you type twice. that should be `Range3.Interior.Pattern = xlNone` . but, i've changed. THANK YOU SO MUCH~

Comment: Fixed that in the answer. Hope it helps.